# Pick a value from an array randomly for a particular day

Tags: php, yii

I have an array which has the id's and my code is as following,

```
    //Random Offer of the day
    $offers = Offer::model()->findAll();
    $randomOffer = null;
    $dataOffer = new GreenPointsActionDataObj();
    if ($offers) {
        $randomNo = mt_rand(0, count($offers) - 1);
        $randomOffer = $offers[$randomNo];
        $dataOffer->id = intval($randomOffer->id);
        $dataOffer->title = $randomOffer->name;
        $dataOffer->thumbUrl = $randomOffer->thumbUrl;
        $dataOffer->description = $randomOffer->description;
    }
    $data[] = $dataOffer;
```

I need this to be day based, for example it should be always one for the day and next day another random but should be same the whole day.

how can i get this done ?

This is my suggestion, when an id is taken, i should maintain it with a day stored in DB.

Comment: you can show based on the weekday number. But each week will have same  offers. is it fine for your?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

**Method 1:**

To get the unique offer for year.

```
$weekday = date('l', time()); // will return the weekday number
$randomOffer = $offers[$weekday];
```

**Method 2**

To get the unique offer for year.

```
$daycnt = date('z', time())+1;
$randomOffer = $offers[$daycnt];
```

**Method 3**

To get the unique offer for month.

```
$cur_date = date('d', time());
$randomOffer = $offers[$cur_date ];
```

Comment: This will only go up to 7 nah. always the same seven will be shown. but my situation is like, i have more than 30 records and it can grow up to any. so if a id comes then it should not come again untill all 30 is used by 30 days

Comment: Oppz.. sorry i overlooked.

Comment: Ok. if you have 30 records, then you can use current date as random number.

Comment: yeah but still it will be same for first 30 days and again the same will be repeated like wise.

Comment: yes. Or you can one thing. You can choose current day count of current year.

Comment: yeah but still date of the year can be a higher number while my count is less. ie date of the year is 150 and my count is 30

Comment: then you can choose current as random number. there is no way.